# How to break down and re-use the curlopt response?

Tags: php, json, parsing, curl, response

I've been struggling with a `curlopt` response for quite some time now and I hope you guys can give me some pointers.

If you please visit the following page: https://niarthgin.com/api/result.php

This will generate a simple response using `curlopt`. Here is the code that I have used in order to get these results:

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.bungie.net/Platform/Destiny2/SearchDestinyPlayer/2/Niarthgin/",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "postman-token: xxxx",
    "x-api-key: xxxx"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
      echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    echo $response;

}
?>
```

I want to break down that response but I have no idea how to do it. For example, in that response, you have a `MembershipType` a `displayName` etc. How can I parse the response individually? Like I know I can parse the response with `json.parse()` but that will only parse a given string. I want to be able to parse the response in segments ..

Thanks for reading! :)

Comment: json_decode($response,true); This will give you an array use print_r($array) to see what the structure is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php)

Comment: I tried using json_decode but I get no results? 

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
   echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
 echo $response;
}

$raw = $response;
$decode = json_decode($raw);
echo $decode;